# Paragraph not centering but parent element is

Tags: html, css

I have a parent section which is set to align center. The H2 in this is displaying center but the paragraph isn't. Any reason why?

```css
.intro {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
    <div class="hero-text"> 
        <h1>The modern office doesn’t <br> always look like, well, an office.</h1>
        <p class="subtitle">Distributed teams, changing business needs, and complex dynamics are redefining the workday. Happy Tools makes it possible for your office to run smoothly, no matter what it looks like or who makes it go.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It should center the texts if you don't set alignment for `hero-text` or `subtitle` classes (or genreall rule for H1 or Paragraph)

Comment: (in Chrome) Inspect the element and check the computed output styles. It shows you what rule overrides others.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Check the h1 element's and p element's classes to see if they have "text-align" styles that are overriding the parents styles. Usually using f12 for developer tools / web inspector will tell you exactly what styles are being overridden.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Answer (score 0):

```css
.intro {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>The modern office doesn’t <br> always look like, well, an office.</h1>
    <p class="subtitle">Distributed teams, changing business needs, and complex dynamics are redefining the workday. Happy Tools makes it possible for your office to run smoothly, no matter what it looks like or who makes it go.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

If I run your code, everything is centered.
Run the snippet and check out out.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Everything is centered. If you want to set the width (left and right) you have to  define this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you any reference to p element in your css that has a text-align : left? A type of normalize.css file could do that. Best way to know that is verifying via your element inspecter of your browser.

Comment: Yes. I'm using a normalized file.

Comment: To me the reason is that you have a reference in a css file to p elements that aligns them to the left.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is all centered.

But you can try also this code:

```
.intro, .intro p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run the code, the p tag is coming in center as you have expected. May be check for the code that overrides it else use important property like below:

```
.intro { text-align: center !important;}
```